# composite primary Key with @Idclass in spring data JPA inserts new record instead of updating when call save method of Spring data JPA

Tags: spring, spring-boot, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

when I try to call the save method on a table which is having composite primary keys only, it always inserts a new record when one to values is changed. how can I achieve an update instead of a new record in DB using spring data JPA?
My table with composite keys is :

```
Table1:
    private int clientTypeId;
    private int clientId;
```

Comment: If it's clientTypeId or clientId you change, it's normal. If not, we're going to need some code instead.

Comment: I need to update clientTypeId for a clientId, I need the JPA to execute the update but it inserts a new record when clientTypeId changes for a clientId.

Comment: You cannot simply update a part of your composite key just as you cannot update a primary key when not using composite keys. It's what makes a row unique. If it changes, it's no longer the same record

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because what is asked is impossible

Comment: I would disagree with  @Nico van Belle. 
there is a workaround for this problem

Comment: please enlighten us then and post an answer

Comment: we can remove existing records from persistent data and save new data

Comment: So your question is "how can I achieve an update instead of a new record" and your solution when I say it cannot be done and you disagree is .....saving a new record.

Comment: yes , that can be achieved by deleting existing and inserting new values :)